# Google Cloud Endpoints require Android SDK level 11 or more

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

It seems that GCP's Endpoints are not compatible with anything below Honeycomb, is there a way to make them backward compatible?

Regarding the error I receive in the logcat:

```
10-06 15:21:33.950    2330-2358/{package} W/System.err﹕ java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: running on Android SDK level 10 but requires minimum 11
10-06 15:21:33.950    2330-2358/{package} W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:119)
10-06 15:21:33.950    2330-2358/{package} W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:69)
10-06 15:21:33.950    2330-2358/{package} W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.extensions.android.AndroidUtils.checkMinimumSdkLevel(AndroidUtils.java:48)
10-06 15:21:33.950    2330-2358/{package} W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.extensions.android.json.AndroidJsonFactory.<init>(AndroidJsonFactory.java:75)
10-06 15:21:33.950    2330-2358/{package} W/System.err﹕ at {package}.fragment.StartFragment$RegistrationLoader.loadInBackground(StartFragment.java:144)
10-06 15:21:33.950    2330-2358/{package} W/System.err﹕ at {package}.fragment.StartFragment$RegistrationLoader.loadInBackground(StartFragment.java:120)
10-06 15:21:33.950    2330-2358/{package} W/System.err﹕ at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:242)
10-06 15:21:33.950    2330-2358/{package} W/System.err﹕ at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:51)
10-06 15:21:33.950    2330-2358/{package} W/System.err﹕ at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:40)
10-06 15:21:33.950    2330-2358/{package} W/System.err﹕ at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:123)
10-06 15:21:33.950    2330-2358/{package} W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
10-06 15:21:33.950    2330-2358/{package} W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
10-06 15:21:33.950    2330-2358/{package} W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
10-06 15:21:33.950    2330-2358/{package} W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
10-06 15:21:33.950    2330-2358/{package} W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: Did you get any workaround? I am also facing same error. Please reply. Thanks.

Comment: I found no solution. I tried stsandro's answer but I couldn't resolve some dependencies and other things broke in my project. I ended up breaking support for those Android versions.

Answer (score 5):

I get the exact same error on my android app. So I looked at the class AndroidJsonFactory and here it is:

```
@TargetApi(11)
@Beta
public class AndroidJsonFactory extends JsonFactory {

public AndroidJsonFactory() {
    AndroidUtils.checkMinimumSdkLevel(11);
}
```

This comes from:

```
compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.18.0-rc') {
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
}
```

in your gradle build file.

Here is something that seem to work for me.

add

```
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.19.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
```

to your gradle build file and the following in to your code:

```
/**
 * Class instance of the JSON factory.
 */
public static final JsonFactory getJsonFactory() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // only for honeycomb and newer versions
        return new AndroidJsonFactory();
    } else {
        return new GsonFactory();
    }
}
```

Then use the getJsonFactory() - method wherever you build your backend service handler. I'll do a little more testing but I think this should work.

Comment: I am also facing similar problem mentioned in question, but in my project I dont have AndroidJsonFactory.java file but I could find AndroidJsonFactory.class file in com.google.api.client.extensions.android.json package. I am getting exception at   Registration.Builder builder = new Registration.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                                    .setRootUrl("https: //project_id/_ah/api/");  Can you have any idea why it is coming? and what would be solution for the same? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [GCP Java tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/clients/android/configure), you can create endpoints using API 9: Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) for the Minimum required SDK. Which means it should support at least gingerbread devices. It might be a problem generating the clients or an inconsistency in the GCP Java Documentation. I've generated clients using Maven Plugin for Eclipse. I'll try to generate clients with Android Studio to see if it makes any difference.